# TypeScript MultyProject referencing

Tags: typescript, reference, compilation

I'm having problems getting my game project to compile correctly.

This is my folder structure.

```
**R1** -> *Engine Project.*
**R2** -> *EngineModule Project.*
**R3** -> *Game Project.*
```

I want the modules to be independent from the engine it self, so i import the modules and the engine separately in the game.

References:

**R1** has no references.
**R2** references the engine project. **R3** references the other 2.

**R2** config file.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "rootDir": "./",
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "es6",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "es5",
        "composite": true,
        "sourceMap": true
    },
    "references": [
        {
            "path": "../R1"
        }
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
        "../R1"
    ]
}
```

**R3** Config file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "es6",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "es5",
        "composite": true,
        "rootDir": "./"
    },
    "references": [
        { "path": "../R1" },
        { "path": "../R2" }
    ]
}
```

This is the error i get:

```
../R2/dist/index.d.ts:1:22 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '../R1'.
1 import { TESTR1 } from "../R1";
```

The **TESTR1** class is exported and when i compile **R2** it does it fine.

This is R3 **index.ts** file.

```
import { TESTR1 } from "../R1";
import { TESTE2 } from "../R2";
```

Comment: Please provide more information about the layout of your folders.  Or you may be able to find the problem yourself by using the `--traceResolution` option to `tsc`.